# Django's ORM. Group by elements with difference

Tags: python, django, orm

I have this Django model:

```
class Visits(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

 def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s : %s (%s)" % (unicode(self.ip), 
                             unicode(self.datetime.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')), 
                             unicode(self.url))
```

It contains all visits to my website. For example, these are all values from DB:

```
<Visits: 127.0.0.1 : 27/11/14 00:00:00 (/)>,
<Visits: 127.0.0.1 : 27/11/14 00:01:00 (/)>, 
<Visits: 127.0.0.1 : 27/11/14 00:09:00 (/)>, 
<Visits: 127.0.0.1 : 27/11/14 00:45:00 (/)>, 
<Visits: 127.0.0.1 : 27/11/14 00:46:00 (/)>
```

I want to write an ORM query which groups values with 15-minutes delta. For example, this query should return `count()==2` (first three values are in first group, second two are in second). How can I do it using Django's ORM?

Comment: this is not simple to do, you should first work out the correct SQL to achieve it then work backwards to the Django ORM. you will likely have to use `extra` method, perhaps a custom aggregation class would be possible, else just `raw` method

Comment: see this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9950573/202168

Comment: By 15 mins delta you mean objects having datetime object having equal to and more then 15 mins right ?

Comment: I guess you first need to annotate the queryset with a timestamp-like value that represents each particular 15-minute window, then aggregate on some other field but grouped by the annotation field. this may help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses

Comment: @michaeluskov If you want result based on distinct ip then how come you are expecting count()==2 for mins 15 or more in case of unique ip 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Here i have four visits and i tried to filter out by minitues grater than 28.

```
>>> visits_count = len([ obj for obj in Visits.objects.all() if obj.datetime.strftime('%M') >  '28'])
>>> visits_count
2
```

It is for the case minitues greater than equal to 28.

```
>>> visits_count = len([ obj for obj in Visits.objects.all() if obj.datetime.strftime('%M') >=  '28'])
>>> visits_count
4
```

Comment: The first answer should be 3 (first, second and two last)

Comment: If you want it to be distinct by ip you can use query "for obj in Visits.objects.distinct('ip')"

Comment: If you want result based on distinct ip then how come you are expecting count()==2 for mins 15 or more in case of unique ip 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Downvoter please give the reason for your downvote ?